# Does python multiprocessing work with Hadoop streaming?

Tags: python-3.x, hadoop-streaming

In Hadoop streaming - where the Mapper and Reducer are written in python - Does it help to make the Mapper process use the `multiprocessing` module? Or does the scheduler prevent the Mapper scripts from running on multiple threads on the compute nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In classic MapReduce there is nothing that stops you from having multiple threads in a mapper or a reducer. The same is true for Hadoop Streaming, you can very well have multiple threads per mapper or reducer. This situation can happen if you have a CPU heavy job and want to speed it up.

If you're doing Hadoop Streaming with Python, you can use the `multiprocessing` module to speed up your mapper phase.

Note that depending on the way your Hadoop cluster is configured (how many JVM mapper/reducer per nodes) you may have to adjust the maximum number of processes you can use.